How to fix a chessboard frame cracked from expansion?
I have a chessboard I made in high school woods class. If I remember right, it's walnut and oak.

It was a lot of fun to make and looks good, but since then the joints in the frame on one side have come apart. I think this is due to the grain direction not being the same between the board and the frame on that side (like is pointed out in this question). I would think that wouldn't be an issue though, except that the bottom of the chessboard was left un-varnished.

Because of that, I think the crack is appearing with seasonal changes in humidity/temperature. Sometimes the crack is a few millimeters wide. Sometimes it's hardly there at all.
Here is a close-up of the joint.

How would I go about fixing this?

Sarcasm alert: here's how you fix this, shrink the wood and then get it to stay shrunk. This is actually impossible as you probably know, hence the sarcasm ^_^


the joints in the frame on one side have come apart. I think this is due to the grain direction not being the same between the board and the frame on that side (like is pointed out in this question).

Correct. This is a perfect example of the potential issue with cross-grain joints, and a classic illustration of why one should not as a rule attempt to picture-frame a table (if using solid wood).
Although it may have been deliberate, i.e. as instructed, the grain of all the blocks being oriented the same maximised the chances of an issue somewhere down the line. Many chessboards that are built essentially the same way alternate the grain direction of the black and white squares, seeking to average out the expansion/contraction effects of the wood.
Or, alternatively, they're not made from solid wood at all.
As I say in the Comments to the linked Q, many chessboards aren't made in the solid, they're veneered pieces; essentially parquetry. And as such the stable veneer substrate takes care of the issue, making picture-framing even a sizeable board (or a tabletop) a non-issue. This method of construction is actually much, much more likely on factory-made commercial boards.

I would think that wouldn't be an issue though, except that the bottom of the chessboard was left un-varnished.

The bottom being unfinished may have been a factor in this, or it may not. Finishes, as a rule, imperfectly seal a wood surface (this is an understatement).
Considering how thinly this is finished — it looks to have a "close to the wood" level of finish on the top — I suspect the same amount of finish applied on the bottom would have only slowed the effect rather than prevented it entirely.

How would I go about fixing this?

There really isn't any perfect fix here.
You could in theory pack out the now-gappy mitre for example. But then, what happens if/when the board subsequently wants to shrink? If the board shrinks (as may be likely as we head into drier months) zero gap left in that mitre gives no room for the frame to close back up. The wood is still going to shrink no matter what, and another issue will crop up.
You could just live with it and embrace it as a well-built, well-finished, attractive but imperfect woodworking project from your high-school days :-)
However, if the mitre does close back up by itself over the coming months you could then try to finish the board more heavily (especially on the bottom, but also adding extra finish to the top) to try to seal the wood off more completely from changes in humidity. Given the gap is actually fairly small, this might work well!

Thanks! I appreciate the thorough response, and your compliments :) If I go with your last suggestion and try to reseal it once it shrinks back down, do I run the risk of more damage to the board if it swells again? I would think not. It would just send a crack through the new layer of varnish, right?

Welcome! It's what we're here for :-) The point of trying the addition of more finish is to seal the wood off more completely from changes in humidity, slowing moisture uptake and loss – lessening the maximum and minimum of the swell/shrink cycle through a typical year. Other than aesthetics, this is finishing's primary function. Here, despite no finish on the bottom, the expansion wasn't too bad. So you can definitely expect an improvement. How much of an improvement is an open question of course, because of all the variables. As best it might be so minimal you won't easily notice it.

At worst it will be, let's say 50% better than currently? That's still a fairly significant improvement given how small the gapping is at the corner currently. BTW, the wider gap at the inside of the mitre is from permanent changes in the wood (perfectly normal changes), so you can't expect that to ever close again unless you do some sawing. "It would just send a crack through the new layer of varnish, right?" Yes. Even the slightest change will open up a gap in the finish. A mere 1/100" is probably enough that you'd see it if you look closely, although you would have to look for it.

Ok cool. Thanks!
